# convert uuid to byte, that works when using UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(b)

Tags: java, uuid

I am converting UUID to byte using this code

```
public byte[] getIdAsByte(UUID uuid)
{
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[16]);
    bb.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
    bb.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
    return bb.array();
}
```

However, if I try to recreate the UUID using this function,

```
public UUID frombyte(byte[] b)
{
    return UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(b);
}
```

It is not the same UUID. Converting a randomUUID back and forth returns two different it.

```
UUID u = UUID.randomUUID();
System.out.println(u.toString());
System.out.println(frombyte(getIdAsByte(u)).toString());
```

prints:

```
1ae004cf-0f48-469f-8a94-01339afaec41
8b5d1a71-a4a0-3b46-bec3-13ab9ab12e8e
```

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [What namespace does the JDK use to generate a UUID with nameUUIDFromBytes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504519/what-namespace-does-the-jdk-use-to-generate-a-uuid-with-nameuuidfrombytes)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
public class UuidUtils {
  public static UUID asUuid(byte[] bytes) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
    long firstLong = bb.getLong();
    long secondLong = bb.getLong();
    return new UUID(firstLong, secondLong);
  }

  public static byte[] asBytes(UUID uuid) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
    bb.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
    bb.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
    return bb.array();
  }
}
```

---

```
@Test
public void verifyUUIDBytesCanBeReconstructedBackToOriginalUUID() {
  UUID u = UUID.randomUUID();
  byte[] uBytes = UuidUtils.asBytes(u);
  UUID u2 = UuidUtils.asUuid(uBytes);
  Assert.assertEquals(u, u2);
}

@Test
public void verifyNameUUIDFromBytesMethodDoesNotRecreateOriginalUUID() {
  UUID u = UUID.randomUUID();
  byte[] uBytes = UuidUtils.asBytes(u);
  UUID u2 = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(uBytes);
  Assert.assertNotEquals(u, u2);
}
```

Comment: This implies everybody agrees on little-endian representation.

Comment: Is this little endian? The ByteBuffer itself is going to start with a BIG_ENDIAN order.

Comment: Yes.  This was tested using x86 (little-endian) based processors.

Comment: @Brice I don't believe "using x86 (little-endian) based processors" is relevant. The [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class has an independent endianness and "_The initial order of a byte buffer is always BIG_ENDIAN_".

Answer (score 20):

that's because `nameUUIDFromBytes` constructs a specific kind of UUID (as the javadoc states).

if you want to convert a byte[] back to a UUID, you should use the UUID constructor.  Wrap a ByteBuffer around the byte[], read the 2 longs and pass them to the UUID constructor.

Comment: An example code for this would be:  
`ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(inputByteArray);  
long firstLong = bb.getLong();  
long secondLong = bb.getLong();

return new UUID(firstLong, secondLong);`

Comment: What if access to the UUID contructor is restricted like in minecraft? I have that problem because Im trying to condense a UUID and some data down to bytes in one big file to create a Shop characteristic of a Plugin for a bukkit server. the file is of binary in array : [0] UUID [1] money [2] points. This would just repeat going down the list in the file.

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer - if you have a different problem, then you should probably open a new question.