# How to insert UUID into RAW(16) column

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, uuid, dbsetup

I have the RAW(16) PK column in Oracle, and trying to insert into it using JDBC:

```
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("insert into COUNTRY (id, state, version, code, name, nationality, issuing_entity, country) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
        stmt.setObject(1, id, Types.BINARY);
```

However, I am getting an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8494)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:7995)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8559)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:225)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setObject(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
at rw.gov.dgie.framework.test.AbstractTestCaseWithDB.tryToInsertCountry(AbstractTestCaseWithDB.java:78)
at rw.gov.dgie.framework.test.AbstractTestCaseWithDB.dbSetup(AbstractTestCaseWithDB.java:62)
at test.rw.gov.dgie.bms.terr.service.TestCountryService.init(TestCountryService.java:37)
```

I am getting the same exception when trying to use DbSetup for inserting test data.

Is there a way to make JDBC insert UUIDs into RAW(16) column?

I am using Oracle JDBC 12.2.0.1.0.

Comment: Can't you save `id.toString()`?

Comment: imho u have to pass something like byte[] to JDBC driver to allow storage of datatype RAW.

Comment: id.toString()? Into RAW(16)? But how?

Comment: @ibre5041, I can write it down as bytes but I need to make DbSetup working. Hibernate works fine

Comment: what about using setBytes() instead of setObject()?

Comment: setBytes() works but not for DbSetup

Answer (score 11):

You must convert the UUID to a byte array. See the method [asBytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893609/convert-uuid-to-byte-that-works-when-using-uuid-nameuuidfrombytesb/29836273) how to do it.

After it the binding is a s simple as using `setBytes`.

Example

```
def stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into TAB_UUID (id, uuid) values (?,?)") 
// bind
stmt.setInt(1,1)
def uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
stmt.setBytes(2,asBytes(uuid)) 
def rowCount = stmt.executeUpdate()
```

Here just for case the link doesn't work  the conversion method UUID to byte array

```
  public static byte[] asBytes(UUID uuid) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[16]);
    bb.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
    bb.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
    return bb.array();
  }
```

Comment: @Serge you are welcome; anyway from my experience, I'd use / allow to use hash codes as PKs only if there are two good reasons, why `sequence` can't be used and that hash code brings a real advantage against a numerical PK. Good luck!

Comment: I am using it due to necessity of merging data from intermediate servers on the main one. I think this way is better than maintaining separate range of sequence values for each server.

Comment: I am using jbdcTemplate,  not preparedStatement/Con,  what do I do then? I need to somehow setBytes(2,   after calling as Bytes function,  if anyone knows, would be great !

Comment: see question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68895766/how-to-insert-uuid-into-raw16-column-with-jdbc-template

Answer (score 5):

Oracle has no real UUID datatype and dealing with `RAW(16)` is really a PITA.

What we do, is to pass the UUID as a string to a SQL statement that uses `hextoraw()`:

```
String sql = "insert into foo (id) values (hextoraw(?))";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
UUID uid = UUID.randomUUID();
pstmt.setString(1, uid.toString().replaceAll("-", ""));
```

Comment: in testing, it does not following this page conversion https://robobunny.com/cgi-bin/guid

Comment: yeah, i was trying to test with oracle, etc

Comment: any idea how to get just the string value? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68886687/java-guid-convert-into-oracle-raw16-string

Answer (score 2):

```
getJdbcTemplate().update("INSERT INTO abc(abc_id, abc_uuid, "
                                       + "VALUES (?, ?)",
                                          abcId, uuidToBytes(abcUuid))
```

Here's a helper method to converet UUID type to bytes.

```
private byte[] uuidToBytes(final UUID uuid) {
        if (Objects.isNull(uuid)) {
            return null;
        }

        final byte[] uuidAsBytes = new byte[16];

        ByteBuffer.wrap(uuidAsBytes)
                  .order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)
                  .putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits())
                  .putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());

        return uuidAsBytes;
    }
```

Comment: you need one more line, see above answer def uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
stmt.setBytes(2,asBytes(uuid))

Comment: this is incorrect, needs set bytes method (2, added after testing

Answer (score 2):

[`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) provides different methods for performing a DML operations like insert. Please, consider for instance `update`.

@MarmiteBomber provides in his/her answer all the necessary information for performing what you need, please, only wrap the code appropriately in the different artifacts defined by Spring.

For example, you can use [`PreparedStatementCreator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/PreparedStatementCreator.html), something like:

```java
jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
  @Override
  public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into TAB_UUID (id, uuid) values (?,?)");
    ps.setInt(1,1);
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    ps.setBytes(2,asBytes(uuid));
    return ps;
  }
});
```

The code can be simplified using lambdas to:

```java
jdbcTemplate.update(con -> {
  PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into TAB_UUID (id, uuid) values (?,?)");
  ps.setInt(1,1);
  UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
  ps.setBytes(2,asBytes(uuid));
  return ps;
});
```

If you prefer, you can use [`PreparedStatementSetter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/PreparedStatementSetter.html) instead:

```java
jdbcTemplate.update("insert into TAB_UUID (id, uuid) values (?,?)", new PreparedStatementSetter() {
  @Override
  public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
    ps.setInt(1,1);
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    ps.setBytes(2, asBytes(uuid));
  }
});
```

Again, the code can be simplified with lambdas:

```java
jdbcTemplate.update("insert into TAB_UUID (id, uuid) values (?,?)", ps -> {
  ps.setInt(1,1);
  UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
  ps.setBytes(2, asBytes(uuid));
});
```

In both examples you explicitly invoke `setBytes` in the underlying prepared statement and use the `asBytes` method from the Marmite answer.