# Java Guid Convert into Oracle Raw(16) String

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, guid

How do I convert a JSON Guid to Oracle Raw(16) String Data Type?

In C# Net, it is Using `ToByteArray()`.

What is the equivalent in Java 8?

The following website will convert, however I need underlying code.

Goal Convert: `A0824186-1E9C-AE47-95E1-1431542C2133` to string `864182A09C1E47AE95E11431542C2133`

https://robobunny.com/cgi-bin/guid

- Standard: `A0824186-1E9C-AE47-95E1-1431542C2133`
- Bracketed: `{A0824186-1E9C-AE47-95E1-1431542C2133}`
- Oracle RAW(16) format: `864182A09C1E47AE95E11431542C2133`
- Oracle hextoraw `HEXTORAW('864182A09C1E47AE95E11431542C2133')`
- SQLServer using Oracle byte order: `0x864182A09C1E47AE95E11431542C2133`

Net Solution Reference: [Convert from Oracle's RAW(16) to .NET's GUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289734/convert-from-oracles-raw16-to-nets-guid)

**Update:**

Is there a way to reverse this function?  [ORACLE RAW in string format to Standard GUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684714/oracle-raw-in-string-format-to-standard-guid) https://stackoverflow.com/a/37685066/15435022

Also, I saw some Javascript source code, maybe find a way to convert into Java

https://github.com/kanekotic/raw-guid-converter/blob/master/lib/guid-to-raw.js

```
const buffer = require('buffer/').Buffer,
    transform = require('./helpers').transform,
    patterns = require('./helpers').patterns

    
const convert = (raw) => {
    const pattern = /([0-9A-Fa-f]{8})-([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})-([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})-([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})-([0-9A-Fa-f]{12})/i
    let guid_parsed = transform(pattern, raw)
    return `${guid_parsed[0]}${guid_parsed[1]}${guid_parsed[2]}${guid_parsed[3]}${guid_parsed[4]}`.toUpperCase()   
 }
 
module.exports = convert
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following code base will work:

```
private byte[] convertToOracleRaw(UUID uuid) {
    String uuidString = uuid.toString().replace("-", "").toUpperCase();
    String finalValue = "";
    finalValue += uuidString.substring(6,8);
    finalValue += uuidString.substring(4,6);
    finalValue += uuidString.substring(2,4);
    finalValue += uuidString.substring(0,2);
    finalValue += uuidString.substring(10,12);
    finalValue += uuidString.substring(8,10);
    finalValue += uuidString.substring(14,16);
    finalValue += uuidString.substring(12,14);
    finalValue += uuidString.substring(16,18);

    finalValue += uuidString.substring(18, uuidString.length());  // final string
    return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(finalValue);  // in hex binary
}
```