# Reproduce uuid from java code in python

Tags: java, python, uuid

In a Java application files are created where the filename is a UUID generated from a protein sequence (e.g. TTCCPSIVARSNFNVCRLPGTPEAICATYTGCIIIPGATCPGDYAN) created using the function `UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes`. This results in the UUID `c6a0deb5-0c4f-3961-9d19-3f0fde0517c2`.

`UUID.namedUUIDFromBytes` doesn't take a namespace as a parameter, whereas in python `uuid.uuid3` does. According to [What namespace does the JDK use to generate a UUID with nameUUIDFromBytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504519/what-namespace-does-the-jdk-use-to-generate-a-uuid-with-nameuuidfrombytes), the namespace should have been passed as part of the name, but it's no longer possible to change the java code.

Is there a way to create a custom namespace in the python code such that it will produce the same UUID's as the Java code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`nameUUIDFromBytes`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/UUID.java#UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes%28byte%5B%5D%29) only takes one parameter, which is supposed to be the concatenation of the namespace and name just like you say. The namespace parameter is supposed to be a `UUID`, and as far as I know, they don't have a `null` value defined.

A "`null` uuid" can be passed to Python's [`uuid3`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/uuid.py#L599) like this. This should work as long as the namespace has a `bytes` attribute (tested with Python 2 and 3):

```
class NULL_NAMESPACE:
    bytes = b''
uuid.uuid3(NULL_NAMESPACE, 'TTCCPSIVARSNFNVCRLPGTPEAICATYTGCIIIPGATCPGDYAN')
# returns: UUID('c6a0deb5-0c4f-3961-9d19-3f0fde0517c2')
```

Comment: Superb. I was trying for ages to turn an empty string into bytes but couldn't find the trick.

Comment: In Python 3 it is no longer possible to mix Unicode strings with encoded strings -  it will result in a `TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly`. I think that `bytes` should by binary string: `bytes = ''.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: @JarekPrzygódzki Good point. I changed `''` to `b''` for Python 3 compatibility.

Comment: Rather than create the class, you can use some (somewhat ugly) code to do this inline: `type('', (), dict(bytes=b''))()` (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1123054) to another question).  So then you can do this as a one liner if needed, e.g.: `python -c "import uuid; print uuid.uuid3(type('', (), dict(bytes=b''))(), 'TTCCPSIVARSNFNVCRLPGTPEAICATYTGCIIIPGATCPGDYAN')"`.

Comment: @Rik - the creation of the class is quite a good approach if you ever need to reuse the constant in any place in your project but I agree with your solution also; as a combined solution you can have

`class Numeric(Enum):   
      NULL_NAMESPACE = type('', (), dict(bytes=b''))()

 uuid.uuid3(Numeric.NULL_NAMESPACE, 'TTCCPSIVARSNFNVCRLPGTPEAICATYTGCIIIPGATCPGDYAN')
# returns: UUID('c6a0deb5-0c4f-3961-9d19-3f0fde0517c2') `

Answer (score 1):

In the case that it is helpful, if you want to do the Java side of this, you can use the following:

```
UUID namespaceUUID = UUID.fromString("9db60607-6b12-41eb-8848-eafd26681583");
String myString = "sometextinhere";

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[16 + myString.getBytes().length]);
buffer.putLong(namespaceUUID.getMostSignificantBits());
buffer.putLong(namespaceUUID.getLeastSignificantBits());
buffer.put(myString.getBytes());

byte[] uuidBytes = buffer.array();

UUID myUUID = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(uuidBytes);
```

This will provide the same output UUID as the following Python:

```
namespaceUUID = UUID('9db60607-6b12-41eb-8848-eafd26681583')
myUUID = uuid.uuid3(namespaceUUID, 'sometextinhere'))
```

Comment: It does not output same UUID as java

Answer (score -1):

@turbomeri's answer is right.. just python code didn't had few mistakes, so corrected the version

````
a = 'sometextinhere'
namespaceUUID = uuid.UUID('9db60607-6b12-41eb-8848-eafd26681583')
print(str(uuid.uuid3(namespaceUUID, a)))```
````